# Using Intent.ACTION_PICK to access the Gallery issues: Camera directory will not let me save an image to a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-gallery

```
public void onClick_DisplayGallery(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
          android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY); 

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
 Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        //Gallery
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY && resultCode ==  
RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap =  
 BitmapFactory.decodeStream
(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedUri));

                //places selected images into bitmap for database use
                originalBitmapImage = bitmap;

                //Process data after image chosen (add image to database)
                process_chosenImage();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
} catch (Exception ex) { /
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gallery not responding",   
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //Reset view
resetView_afterImageChosen();
}
```

> When I select images from other galleries besides Camera Directory
>       and Download Directory, I can save the images to my database with no 
>       problems. Also, when I run my program in the emulator, everything runs 
>       smoothly. However, when it comes to actual devices, my app crashes. I
>       use Dell Venue 8 to test on actual device, but cannot connect it to the
>       computer in order to debug it.
>
> How can I save an image to my database from the Camera Directory after 
>       accessing it from the Gallery? I can save images from other directories, 
>       except as I mentioned before, I cannot save images from the Camera 
>       directory and the Downloads directory.

Comment: Pls post your logcat

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. What happened is that when I tried to convert Uri to bitmap (then to byte[] ) and place it into my database, I could not access the camera folder. What I did is instead of converting Uri to bitmap, I converted the Uri into byte[] and placed it directly into my database and that did the trick.